# MvvmCross/MvvmCross-SQLite support for profile 259 on Xamarin (.Net 4.5)

Tags: sqlite, plugins, xamarin, 64-bit, mvvmcross

I'm working with Xamarin and MvvmCross.
I'm using the "Community MvvmCross SQLite-Net" plugin.
I need to change my PCL profile to 259.
This plugin does not support profile 259 on Xamarin (.Net4.5).

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the Nuget has not been released but I updated the source code of the community sqlite plugin to be profile 259.  You'll have to download and compile yourself until we get a package released.